# how to decompile a DLL file to source code?

Tags: dll, compilation, decompiler, dotpeek

i need to decompile [this DLL file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1HyOD2oTWbuOZabDXNpRMYaXIhpiqoEbi/view?usp=sharing).
I searched the whole internet and I found no one is having this problem with Dot peek said it not supported.

I try dot peek and it said not supported

Comment: The linked DLL file is inaccessible. If dotPeek says that it's not supported, then it's probably not a .NET DLL but something else, e.g. C++. You need a tool for native code then, e.g. IDA Pro.

Comment: you can acces the link

Comment: i cant understand hex and assblely code,can you find another that could turn the compile dll into the source code?